# count xml nodes under specific node

Tags: java, xml

```
<element>
  <slot name="slot1">
    <port status="active"/>
    <port status="inactive"/>
  </slot>
  <slot name="slot2">
    <port status="active"/>
  </slot>
</element>
```

`NodeList listOfElement = doc.getElementsByTagName("port");` this gives total number of port in xml file.

I need to find out how many ports are under slot1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this?

```
var slot1 = doc.getElementsByName("slot1");
var slot1_count = slot1[0].getElementsByTagName("port").length;
```

Comment: NodeList listOfShelfs = doc.getElementsByTagName("shelfs");
              int slot1_count = ((Element)(listOfShelfs.item(0))).getElementsByTagName("port").getLength();
              System.out.println(slot1_count);
thnx...

Comment: System.out.println? this is Java command, didn't you mean `console.log(slot1_count)` or `document.write(slot1_count)`

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use xpath to filter out the resulting list:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();            
NodeList list=(NodeList) xpath.evaluate("/element/slot[@name='slot1']/port",doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

This will only count the ports that are under slot with name `'slot1'`.

Comment: You could also leverage the XPath count function with your approach:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228182/count-xml-nodes-under-specific-node/7230574#7230574

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `javax.xml.xpath` libraries in Java SE, and leverage the `count` function:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XPath xp = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        InputSource xml = new InputSource(new FileInputStream("input.xml"));
        double count = (Double) xp.evaluate("count(//slot[@name='slot1']/port)", xml, XPathConstants.NUMBER);
    }

}
```